# Merged cells and uploader

Tags: excel

I have macro to upload data from excel file to pptx. I need to give a range for slides but firsts cells are merged, so the range starts from merged cells A+B 1, how can I write it down, so that macro works properly?. In other cases it was simple e.g range A1:T40, now in case of merged cells macro doesn`t work. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. But maybe this helps to shed some light on merged areas: `For Each cell In Range("A1:G10"): Debug.Print cell.MergeArea.Address: Debug.Print cell.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Address: Next cell`. Note that you can only copy / paste data from Excel to PowerPoint which is rectangular. So, if you want to copy the range A1:T40 and T40 is part of a merged with T41 then you have a problem because the overall range would be A1:T40 + T41 (without A41:S41). That's not a rectangular shape and therefore you cannot copy it over (unless you un-merge the area).

Answer (score 0):

If your code is using a specific range then why not replace that with the current region:

`Range("A1").CurrentRegion`